# Opening A Program With A Python Script

Tags: python

I am trying to get a script to open the "Stellarium" application on my laptop, but it keeps giving me this error...

***"Windows cannot find "stellarium.exe." Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."***

I am guessing something is wrong with the "prog =" syntax.

Here are files' locations...

```
C:\Stellarium\Stellarium.exe
C:\Stellarium\Scripts\StartUp.ssc
```

Double-clicking either the script file or the *.exe will open The Stellarium application as expected.

Here is the code...

```
stellocation = "C:\\Stellarium"

...

prog = "start /d ""+stellocation+"" stellarium.exe --startup-script startup.ssc"
os.system(prog)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Make sure that the casing is correct, i.e. it's `Stellarium.exe`, not `stellarium.exe`.

Comment: I suggest to first try to figure out the correct command string by directly using the command line. If it does what you want, try to reproduce is in python.

Comment: @Andrew Wei - Thanks for the reply, but correcting case still produced the error. Does this mean the syntax is correct?

Comment: @po.pe - I will try your suggestion and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you messed up the `+` and the `"`. You effectively call

```
'start /d +stellocation+ stellarium.exe --startup-script startup.ssc'
```

Try

```
prog = "start /d " +stellocation+ " stellarium.exe --startup-script startup.ssc"
```

or even better: use `subprocess.run`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['start', '/d', stellocation, 'stellarium.exe', '--startup-script', 'startup.ssc'])
```

I have no windows around, so I did not try.

Answer (score 0):

did you change the directory using `os.chidr(location of files)` first?
 I think that's why it can't see the `exe` file.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks.